# Cumulative sum by months in Powerbi DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

I want to show the cumulative sum per month, I have the number per month but need to show the sum up of previous months in each month..

I used the following measure:

```
RT FAC = 
CALCULATE (
     CALCULATE(SUM('Injuries'[Total]), 'Injuries'[Classification] = "FAC"),
      FILTER(ALLSELECTED('Calendar Table'),
     'Calendar Table'[Date]<= 'Calendar Table'[Date]))
```

But it gave me the total in all the months:

[image]

How can I show the running total such as:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What IF you try this with small change?

```
RT FAC =
VAR MaxDate =
    MAX ( 'Calendar Table'[Date] )
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( 'Injuries'[Total] ),
        FILTER (
            ALL ( 'Injuries'[Classification] ),
            'Injuries'[Classification] = "FAC"
        ),
        FILTER ( ALLSELECTED ( 'Calendar Table' ), 'Calendar Table'[Date] <= MaxDate )
    )
```